# Using yeoman generator-angularjs-library

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator

Trying to use angularjs-library generator. I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@0.0.3 wants karma@~0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-chrome-launcher@0.0.2 wants karma@~0.9.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-requirejs@0.2.1 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.3 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-script-launcher@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.2.1 wants karma@>=0.11.14
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.2 wants karma@>=0.9

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\InteliJ\BYGA\testlib
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\InteliJ\BYGA\testlib\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it -

```
npm rm karma-coffee-preprocessor
```

It was the only module that required karma version ~0.11